# How to add files in docker container after volumes are mounted/attched?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to add files to a volume in the phase

- during a build 
    **but**
- after the volumes are attached/mounted?

E.g. if you run docker-compose the volumes get created in this phase, but the volumes are created just before the container get started. So a phase far too late to have files added during docker-compose.

E.g. I want to add binary files of a database to the volumes as a init of the database.

Comment: why not to just `COPY` the binary in Build stage ?

Comment: or you can use https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add files to a volume [...] during a build

No.  Whatever volumes you might attach to the container later aren't attached during the build sequence, and might not even exist.  You can't guarantee that a given image will always be run with the same volumes attached in any case.

The usual approach is to include a program that can create the initial filesystem structure if needed (or perhaps copy "seed" data out of the image).  Write an entrypoint script that looks at the filesystem and decides if it needs to do that first-time initialization or not, then runs the main container command.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am docker-entrypoint.sh
if [ ! -f /var/data/some-file.txt ]; then
  initialize_data_tree /var/data
fi
exec "$@"
```

If it's an image that you built yourself from a Linux-distribution base, another possibility is taking advantage of the Docker feature that [named volumes can be populated with data from the image](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container).  There are some important caveats to it: it only happens if the volume is empty when the container starts (usually on first startup), if the directory is marked as a `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile then you can't add data afterwards, and this path doesn't work in Kubernetes.

> I want to add binary files of a database to the volumes as a init of the database.

If you have an SQL-format dump (not the binary files) then the standard database images support a `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory.  Place the dump there (either in a dervied image or bind-mounting it at first startup) and the image's entrypoint will run files in that directory as part of the first-time database initialization.

Conversely, since the standard database images declare their data directories as `VOLUME`, you can't create a derived image that has data there.

One other thing you can do is start the database once with a host directory bind-mounted in to the container (not a named volume) and do your first-time setup.  Stop the container and tar up that directory.  Now when you need a database clone, untar the binary content and bind-mount the new directory into new container.  (It might be nice if Docker supported this pattern natively, but it doesn't.)